# Mars MIPS 3x3 Matrix multiplication.

Tags: c, mips

I'm following this fragment of a C code and i'm trying to translate it to the MIPS assembly language:

```
for(int i = 0; i < DIM; i++){       /* Row counter */
    for(int j = 0; j < DIM; j++){      /* Column counter */
      ri = i * DIM + j;                /* Calculate R index */
      r[ri] = 0;                       /* Initialize the entry to zero */
      for (int k = 0; k < DIM; k++){   /* Now perform the inner product */
        ai = i * DIM + k;              /* Calculate the A index */
        bi = k * DIM + j;              /* Calculate the B index */
        r[ri] = r[ri] + a[ai] * b[bi]; /* In the lab I used r[ri] += a[ai] * b[bi] */
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the MIPS code.

Before the `fork` i need to initialize the entry to zero just like in the C code : `r[ri] = 0;` but i dont know how, i try to use `la   $t4, $zero` but it doesnt work. it say "too few or incorrectly formatted operands".

```
        .text               # Indicate that everything below is code
        .globl  main            # The entry point is called main

main:   la      $t0, DIMSQ      # Load the address of DIM*DIM
        lbu     $t0, 0($t0)     # Load the value of [DIM*DIM], re-use $t0
        la      $t1, DIM        # Load the address of DIM
        lbu     $t1, 0($t1)     # Load the value of [DIM], re-use $t1

# Capture the first matrix element by element

        la      $a0, msg1       # Load the string address
        la      $a1, MATA    # Load the address of A[0]
        add     $a2, $a1, $t0   # Check dimension + base address
        jal     input           # Call the capture subroutine

# Capture the second matrix element by element

        la      $a0, msg2       # Load the string address
        la      $a1, MATB       # Load the address of B[0]
        add     $a2, $a1, $t0   # Check dimension + base address
        jal     input           # Call the capture subroutine

# Perform the sum of Matrix A * Matrix B

            xor     $t2, $t2, $t2   # i = 0
   fori:    xor     $t3, $t3, $t3   # j = 0
   forj:    mul     $t4, $t1, $t3   # temp = DIM * j
            add     $t4, $t4, $t2   # temp = j * DIM + i
   fork:    xor     $t9, $t9, $t9   # k = 0
            la      $t5, MATA    # Load the address of A[0]
            add     $t5, $t5, $t4   # temp += Address of A[0]
            lbu     $t6, 0($t5)  # Load A[temp]
            lbu     $t7, 9($t5)      # Load B[temp]
            mul     $t6, $t2, $t1
            add     $t6, $t6, $t9
            mul     $t7, $t9, $t1
            add     $t7, $t7, $t3 
            mul      $t6, $t6, $t7  # C[temp] = A[temp] * B[temp]
            sb      $t6, 18($t5)    # Store C[temp]
            addi    $t3, $t3, 1     # j++
            bne     $t3, $t1, forj  # j < DIM? goto forj
            addi    $t2, $t2, 1     # i++
            bne     $t2, $t1, fori  # i < DIM? goto fori
            addi    $t9, $t9, 1
            bne $t9, $t9, fork 


# Now display the result

        la      $t1, MATC   # Load the address of C[0]
        add     $t2, $t0, $t1   # Add dimension to the base address

out:    li      $v0,4           # mesg1 asking for Matrix B element
        la      $a0, msg3
        syscall

        lbu     $a0, 0($t1)     # load the result
        li      $v0,1           # system call that prints an integer
        syscall 

        li      $v0,4           # prints a '\n'
        la      $a0, cr
        syscall

        addi    $t1, $t1, 1     # increment index pointer
        bne     $t2, $t1, out   # i < DIM?

        li      $v0,10          # system call 10, exit
        syscall

#
# 
#
input:  move    $s0, $a0        # Store the address of the original string
        li      $v0,4           # Call the print string system call
        syscall                 # $a0 is already loaded

        li      $v0,5           # system call that reads an integer
        syscall 

        bgtz    $v0, validA     # check if the input is greater than zero

        li      $v0,4           #let user know something was not OK
        la      $a0, error
        syscall

        move    $a0, $s0        # restore the original string
        j       input           # not valid ask for the number again

validA: 
        sb      $v0, 0($a1)     # store value for matrix A
        addi    $a1, $a1, 1     # increment index pointer
        bne     $a2, $a1, input

        jr      $ra             # return to the caller

#
# These are the space allocations for the three matrices (9 elements each)
# and their dimensions (3 x 3)
#
        .data
MATA:   .space 9
MATB:   .space 9
MATC:   .space 9
DIMSQ:  .byte 09
DIM:    .byte 03

msg1:   .asciiz "Enter Matrix A element (positive number):  "
msg2:   .asciiz "Enter Matrix B element (positive number):  "
msg3:   .asciiz "Result element:  "
error:  .asciiz "Error, the number must be positive\n"
cr:     .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: `la` stands for Load Address. `$zero` is a register, not an address. Hence you should use `move $t4,$zero` if you want to clear `$t4`.

Comment: @Michael i added that but the programm prints {12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
with any value in both matrices. (A & B)

Comment: Use the debugging features of the simulator to find why you're storing the wrong values (i.e. set breakpoints at places of interest, single-step through important pieces of code, and inspect the values of all relevant registers and memory locations).